# AWS: Master user in RDS MySQL dose not have DBA role

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds

I created a MySQL RDS instance. When I connected to this instance using the **master user** which I specified when creating this instance, I realized I do not have DBA role and obviously I do not have the permission to make this master user the DBA. This produces all sorts of problems. Why can't I be the DBA? Don't I own my own AWS account and my database?

Comment: If you had the `SUPER` privilege, you could break things that RDS is responsible for maintaining for you.  RDS is a managed service, so you don't get the entire superset of footgun privileges.

Answer (score 0):

RDS is a service. The user/password you choose when you created is the "admin" account that can do things like create databases and create new grants. So try that user.

Comment: Yes I used that user but it doesn't have DBA role